# Back button with Express 4.3.0

Tags: node.js, session, express, back-button

I'm using a simple cookie session with hashing for the password. For Express 3.x I was using the following code with a custom middleware in order to avoid that a non logged user is allowed to see not authorized data:

```
res.header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, private, no-store, must-revalidate, max-stale=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
res.header('Pragma', 'no-cache');
res.header('Expires', 0);
```

The above code is not working with Express 4.3.0. It means if a user log out and use the back button, then this user is allowed to see old data that need authorization. Any idea?

Comment: Well, it is not working with Chromium (on Ubuntu 14.04), because with Firefox (also in Ubuntu) is working ok. –  uyjco0 6 mins ag

Comment: Chromium in some way is caching the form data (with the user and password) .. then using the back button the browser ask for "Confirm form resubmission" and the user get logged again.